# How do you go through an array of key and value pairs and then assign them to a new Hash object?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

```
array = Array.new
y  = Hash.new 
x = Hash.new
y["First"] = "Moses"
y["Last"] = "Kim"
x["First"] = "John"
x["Last"] = "Snow"
array.push(y)
array.push(x)

p array



hash = Hash.new
hash['listing'] = Hash.new
y = array.each do |a|
  a.each do |key,value|
    hash['listing'][key] = value
  end
end

p hash
```

I would like the data to be like:

```
{ listing: { First: Moses, Last: Kim}, { First: John, Last: Snow}}
```

Comment: The way you would like the data to be is not a valid hash. The second value is not a key value pair. Do you want every entry to have the key `:listing`? That won't work of course...

Comment: What does the original "array of key and value pairs" look like?

Answer (score 1):

`{ listing: { First: Moses, Last: Kim}, { First: John, Last: Snow}}` is not valid.

The sub-hashes need to be in an array:
`{ listing: [{ First: Moses, Last: Kim}, { First: John, Last: Snow}]}`

And that can be constructed from you code with:

```
array = Array.new
y  = Hash.new 
x = Hash.new
y["First"] = "Moses"
y["Last"] = "Kim"
x["First"] = "John"
x["Last"] = "Snow"
array.push(y)
array.push(x)
{ listing: array }
```

Or just
`{ listing: [x, y]}`